# Square root of a parabolic equation

Tags: quadratics, conic-sections

Lets say I have a parabola of the following form:

$$
y = ax^2 + bx + c, \tag{1}
$$

where, $a\ne 0, b\ne 0, c\ne 0$. Now, how the following graph should look like?

$$
\sqrt{y} = \sqrt{ax^2 + bx + c}. 
$$

I understand that in a specific case(not related to ours), if $y = x^2, $ then $\sqrt{y}$ is no longer a parabola. However, I have tried to graph a parabola of the form (1) and then took the square root. The result looked like another parabola except it was not as smooth as the original. Is there anything general we can say about taking the square root of a parabola?

Comment: Zoom out further on the graph. I don’t think it will look like a parabola. Also try different quadratic functions, including one with two roots and one with exactly one root.

Comment: I see! Zooming out showed that it looks like an absolute value function. Is that correct?

Comment: $\sqrt{y}$ is well-defined only for those $x \in \mathbb{R}$, for which $y\geq0$. So, if you take e.g. the parabola $y=-x^2-1$, then "there is no graph" of $\sqrt{y}$. Similarly, if you take, say, $y=x^2-x$, then $\sqrt{y}$ is only well-defined for $x \in \mathbb{R}\backslash (0,1)$. So there are certainly cases where the graph of $\sqrt{y}$ does not resemble a parabola.

Comment: The results you got from zooming out sound correct. Asymptotically, the function is like an absolute value function.